# Undefined method `configure' in an own engine initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, initialization

I'm writing an engine for a project and want to make an initializer for the engine with configuration variables for it.

I thought that I only need to write a initializer like this:

```
MyEngine.configure do |config|
  config.configuration_variable = 1
end
```

But when i try to start the engine dummy app (after copying the initializer in the dummy app) i get this error:

```
C:/path_to_app/test/dummy/config/initializers/my_engine.rb:1:in `<top (required)>':
undefined method `configure' for MyEngine:Module (NoMethodError)
from C:/RubyOnRails/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'

[...]
```

What's my fault? Where and how do I have to define configure?
And last question: is there a good tutorial for writing a own initializer for engines?
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of configuring is just a syntax sugar over assigning to class variables.

```
module MyEngine
  class << self
    def configure
      yield self
    end

    attr_accessor :configuration_variable, :configuration_variable2
  end
end
```

The `.configure` method just yields itself giving you access to the class variables directly.

```
MyEngine.configure do |config|
  config.configuration_variable  = 1
  config.configuration_variable2 = 2
end

MyEngine.configuration_variable # => 1
MyEngine.configuration_variable2 # => 2
```

Note that really it's just a syntax, you can assign to the variable without the configure block.

```
MyEngine.configuration_variable = 3
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great! But where do I have to define the first codeblock (`class << self [...]`)? In the `lib/my_engine/engine.rb`? And if I can define the variables directly, why do many other gems define them by using the `.configure do |config|` block?

Comment: @Kagutsuchi Yeah, that seems like a good place to put it. In general it doesn't really matter as long as it's available to the user. As for the second question, it's really just a convenience thing - you don't have to repeat the name of the module. I personally use the block if I want to set more than one setting, otherwise I'll just assign directly.